# Which ESP32 board should I use?

Tags: wireless, arduino

I have robot. The brain is an arduino mega with this
[shield](http://www.elektrobot.hu/termek.php?filename=Arduino_Shield_H-Bridge_L293D_dual.html&i=1932).

Pictures are below.
Right now I am at the pont where I want to replace the arduino with an esp32. Which esp32 board do you recommend?
Basic needs:

drive 4 dc motor independetly
drive one servo motor
accept signal from 5 (7 in the future) tcrt5000 ir sensor
accept signal from 4 optogate (for the encoders)
accept signal from the ultrasonic sensor
driven by and capabel of charging 2 or 4 lion battery 18650
and also the smartness of the esp32 wifi bt touch sensor etc...

[image: model]
[image: bodymodel]
[image: arduino with the shield]
[image: top]
[image: front left]
[image: front right]

Comment: Why ESP32 in particular?

Comment: As far as I know that is the most common "all-in-one" board around.
And I am familier with Arduino IDE.